# Need to delete packages from '/boot' directory

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, disk-usage

I'm very new to Linux so please bear with me. I attempted to upgrade to 14.04 from 12.04.02 I received the error:

```
"The following packages have unmet dependencies"
```

I ran `apt-get -f install` and received more errors. `apt-get autoremove` also gives me the `dependencies error`.

When I run `uname -a` it shows that I'm running `3.2.0-56` and the dependencies tell me the `package is dependent on 3.2.0-65` So my question is can I safely delete all the other packages in `/boot` to recover some space? That seems to be the issue because there is only 200 MB or so available.There are numerous packages that I believe I should be able to delete:

```
3.2.0-55 and 3.2.0.-57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 63 and 64.
```

Comment: You should never delete a package manually. If you want to remove any package remove is using `sudo apt-get remove <package_name>`. But you need to fix this dependency issue.

Comment: Please, specify more information, more lines from error messages. 200Mb free in boot is normal.

Comment: Good point. I believe I did know that but I appreciate the reminder. That being said is it ok to remove the packages that aren't my current kernel and the one I'm attempting to upgrade to?

Comment: Here's what I get: root@server:/# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic-pae but it is n
ot installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

Comment: To know how to remove old kernel from /boot using command line , see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install` first.

Comment: I did. The output is too long to post here. Let me know if there's any specific parts of the output that would help. Thanks.

Comment: ulcha - It states that /boot is using 99.1% of the 227MB I believe that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to not delete but move them instead to a temporary location (ex a USB drive or a different partition).

Removing them does not remove the package, and if you later need to remove those packages you may get some problems.

After you freed up some space, you can then try to fix your dependencies issues and then uninstall all those unneeded kernels. If you get some problem you just move the files again to /boot as needed.

Also if you have only one partiton (ie / and /boot are on the same partition) it may be easier to cleanup some space in other locations (ex: `/var/cache/apt`)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into that now. Like I said, very new to Linux. I inherited this server (several actually) and am trying to get them up to date. I'm not sure if  'ls -alh'  is showing me how much space is actually in each location. They're mostly showing 20K.

Comment: I found this in another thread:Removing and reinstalling linux-generic will solve this issue.To do this,try the below command on virtual console(ctrl+alt+F1)

sudo apt-get purge linux-generic    
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic     Anyone think that would work or too risky?

Comment: I moved all packages except the current version and the version I'm updating to (that has the dependencies) to a different directory. It freed up quite a bit of space but there's only 168M and the installer says I will need 190M for downloads. Any way to get around this?

Comment: What is the output of `df -h`?

Comment: Filesystem                                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted
 on
/dev/mapper/zebra-root                             984G  757G  177G  82% /
udev                                               494M   12K  494M   1% /dev
tmpfs                                              201M  596K  200M   1% /run
none                                               5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lo
ck
none                                               501M     0  501M   0% /run/sh
m
/dev/sda1                                          228M  115M  101M  54% /boot

Comment: Wow, sorry I don't know how to format in these comments

Comment: No prob. The space should be enough. A new kernel should only take ~30MB in /boot (a lot of other files will be installed in your root partition, which has plenty of space).

Comment: Thanks, you were correct about the space. I was able to successfully upgrade. Not sure how to mark your answer as correct or if I can't since I'm new. But I appreciate your insight.